# Firebase Cloud Messaging -> schedule dynamically

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an Android  Application where users can decide when to receive notification (user selects exact time to receive firebase notifications).To do this,  I need to implement a notification schedule dynamically. Is there any way to schedule firebase push notifications programmatically?
Thank you

Comment: You should use, Notification Manager for this, not remote push notifications. Basically set an alarm manager for your desired time, create notifications in OnReceive method of Alarm manager

Comment: I linked a relevant answer. For more, see: See https://www.google.com/search?q=Is+there+any+way+to+schedule+firebase+push+notifications+programmatically%3F

Answer (score 1):

1- If your implementation can be handled in local, you can use Notification Manager for this, not remote push notifications. Basically set alarms for your desired times, create notifications in OnReceive method of Alarm manager and notify the system

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification

2- If you want to have more control over your notification system and dynamically manage your remote notifications, you can make it via Firebase Admin SDK.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup